# Tuple model leads to null post parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here the Index GET method of my Controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    var models = new Tuple<List<Order>, List<Operator>>(await _context.Orders.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.State == orderState).ToListAsync(), _liveData.Operators);
    return View(models);
}
```

in the related view I display all the rows, and they have a dropdown:

```
@model Tuple<List<Order>, List<Operators>>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Orders", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "form1" }))
{
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Item1.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.Item1[i].Id)
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Item1[i].Number)
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Item1[i].Quantity)
        <select class="custom-select" required>
            <option value="None" selected>Select one</option>
            @foreach (var op in Model.Item2)
            {
                <option value="@op.Name">@op.Name</option>
            }
        </select>
    }
}
```

and here my not working post handler:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(List<Order> orders, List<Operator> op)
{
    // both orders and op are null
}
```

I was expecting the same model I passed to the view, but instead they are both null.

Is there an error in the Tuple syntax?

### EDIT

If this might change something, I add here how Order and Operator are defined in controller:

```
public class OrdersController : Controller
{
    public MyContext _context { get; set; }
    public LiveData _liveData { get; set; }

    public OrdersController(MyContext context, LiveData liveData)
    {
        _context = context;
        _liveData = liveData;
    }
}
```

in DAL:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public IConnectionManager ConnectionManager { get; set; }
    public MyContext() : base("MyContext") { }

    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class LiveData : IDisposable
{
    public MyContext _context { get; set; }

    public LiveData(MyContext context)
    {
        _context = context;

        Operators = new List<Operator>();
    }

    public List<Operator> Operators  { get; set; }
}
```

finally, I inject them using Autofac:

```
public class AutofacContainer
{
    public IContainer Container { get; set; }
    public AutofacContainer()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
        builder.RegisterType<MyContext>().PropertiesAutowired();
        builder.RegisterType<LiveData>().PropertiesAutowired().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        Container = builder.Build();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseAutofacActivator(Container);
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacDependencyResolver(Container));
    }
}
```

Comment: The model coming back up would be the `Tuple<>` so your model should be `Tuple<List<Order>, List<Operators>>` in your Action. it just posts the model up that is bound to the view model.

Comment: You cannot use a `Tuple`. A `Tuple` has no parameter-less constructor therefore cannot be initialized in your POST method. Your editing data - ALWAYS create a view model to represent what you want to edit/display in the view (and view models do not contain data models)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Got it, I didn't understand that caveat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view is strongly type to `Tuple<List<T>,List<U>>` while in your action method you have specified two parameters which are `List<T>` and `List<U>`, the for post will get binded to the actual model, so you should change your action method to have same type as input parameter which your view is strongly typed to like:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(Tuple<List<Order>,List<Operator>> model)
{
    // do something here using model 
}
```

But the above will still not work as `Tuple` does not contains a parameterless constructor so framework will not be able to bind the model in post methid.

You can achieve this by creating a **ViewModel** which would hold both the collections like:

```
public class OrderOperatorViewModel
{
     public List<Order> Orders {get;set;}
     public List<Operator> Operators {get;set;}
}
```

and then in action populate it and return back:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    var models = new OrderOperatorViewModel();
    // fetch data and set properties here 
    return View(models);
}
```

and then in view use it :

```
@model OrderOperatorViewModel
```

and now in action :

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(OrderOperatorViewModel model)
{
    // todo here
}
```

Comment: The first solution doesn't work due to "System.MissinMethodException: no parameterless constructor defined for the object". I'm afraid this because both Order and Operator coming from dependency injection. I will add this in the question.

Comment: As StephenMuecke I cannot use a `Tuple` in this scenario.Your second way (creating a `ViewModel`) works.